# bash vs zsh man page search feature differs

Tags: linux, bash, zsh, sh

I'm switching to zsh from bash, but I just realized that when I'm in a man page in bash and use `/` to search, I can use the hyphen `-` like this:
`/-V` and all `-V` occurences will be found, as expected.

## But

in zsh, when I do the same, in the same man page, using the hyphen finds nothing. But using just use the `/V` with no hyphen, all the `V`s are found..

I tried to escape the hyphen with `/\-V` but no luck. What could be causing this? I use this all the time and it would be very annoying if I have to switch to bash to search a man page.

Comment: This shouldn't have anything to do with your shell. Maybe with your terminal emulator (xterm, konsole, iterm, ...). Or you have some fancy stuff (xmod's) in your .zshrc. Start with `zsh -f` and check if you still get this behavior.

Comment: I actually figured out what the issue was.  The dash in the bash man page was a dash (-), but the dash in the zsh page was actually a minus sign (−).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dash in the bash man page was a dash (-), but the dash in the zsh man page was actually a minus sign (−). It's a strange thing because if you try to use the minus sign in zsh the command will not work. This is not every man page and I don't know how common it is, but the command man page I saw this on was the `command` command.